# Full list of possible names for custom operators in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there a full list (or an exhaustive rule) of the possible names one can give to a custom infix operator in OCaml?

Comment: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#sec71

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#infix-symbol), infix operators must match the regular expression `[-=<>@^|&+*/$%][-!$%&*+./:<=>?@^|~]*`

Their precedence and associativity depends on the first character and you can find the full table [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html).